# Have an object fade in and out of existence

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a view that sets its `hidden` when the user taps the main view. I need the view to fade in and out of existence so it looks smoother than just disappearing.

Heres my code so far (It's inside a touches event):

```
    if (!isShowing) {
        isShowing = YES;
        myView.hidden = YES;
                    //Needs to fade out here


}

    else {
        isShowing = NO;
        myView.hidden = NO;
                    //Needs to fade in here

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap your code like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

if (!isShowing) {
    isShowing = YES;
    myView.hidden = NO
}
else {
    isShowing = NO;
    myView.hidden = YES
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

or simplify it to this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

isShowing = !isShowing;
myView.hidden = isShowing? NO : YES;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

You might also want to use `UIView`'s `setAnimationDuration:`, `setAnimationCurve:`, or `setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:` methods to customize how the view fades in and out.

Comment: Hmmmm... couldn't get it to work. Do I need to replace UIView with something? Im still new to cocoa.

Comment: UIView is the class that has the methods.  Does the view never show up at all?  Are you sure it exists and is a subview of whatever view is on screen?

Comment: Yes the view does show up and it is a subview of the main view. I tried doing [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0]; but no luck.

Comment: Did animating `hidden` work?  Now that I look into it, I think you maybe you need to animate the `alpha` property.

Comment: I did switch it to alpha and then ran into another issue. The hidden was hiding it before it could animate out so I just removed hidden and used alpha.

Answer (score 6):

I've never had luck with animating hidden. Instead, animate alpha.

Comment: That is exactly how i do it.  Take the .alpha property from 1 to 0 to hide and from 0 to 1 to show.  Remember to wrap them in the beginAnimation and commitAnimation blocks.

Comment: Or use the block form (`animateWithDuration:animations:`).

Comment: 'hidden' is a boolean property. It cannot be animated. Indeed animating alpha is the right way to do it